# Issues with creating a copy of an argument in C

Tags: c, string, int

I am converting string arguments into ints I am having an issue where the first argument is not copying and converting to a string while the second argument is working just fine. I am removing the first character of the string array and printing out the rest of the string as an int.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>



   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {


    char numcpy1[sizeof(argv[1])-1];
    char numcpy2[sizeof(argv[2])-1];

    int  i, len1, len2;

    int result1=0;
    int result2=0;


    //Access first character for base
    printf("%c \n", argv[2][0]);
    printf("%c \n", argv[3][0]);


    //Remove first character for number1 and number 2
    if(strlen(argv[2]) > 0)
    {
         strcpy(numcpy1, &(argv[2][1]));
    }
    else
    {
         strcpy(numcpy1, argv[2]);
    }
    len1 = strlen(numcpy1);

    if(strlen(argv[3]) > 0)
    {
         strcpy(numcpy2, &(argv[3][1]));
    }
    else
    {
         strcpy(numcpy2, argv[3]);
    }
    len2 = strlen(numcpy2);

    //Turn remaining string characters into an int
    for(i=0; i<len1; i++)
    {
         result1 = result1 * 10 + ( numcpy1[i] - '0' );
    }

    for(i=0; i<len2; i++)
    {
         result2 = result2 * 10 + ( numcpy2[i] - '0' );
    }

    printf("%d \n", result1);
    printf("%d \n", result2);


    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
b
b
-4844
1010
```

What I want:

```
b
b
1000
1010
```

Comment: You do know that `sizeof` is computed at compile time, not run time. Anyway why the -1

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer to `char`, so `sizeof(argv[1])` gives you the size of that pointer.

Comment: Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string, not `sizeof()`. And why are you subtracting 1?

Comment: What's the point of copying the arguments? You're not making any modifications to them. (And even if you were, that would be allowed unless you needed the original as well for something else.)

Comment: Why write your own code to convert to `int` instead of using `atoi()` or `strtol()`?

Comment: Your numcpy1 and numcpy2 are sized for argv[1] and argv[2] but the rest of the code uses argv[2] and argv[3].  Was this intentional?

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest remove the statement: `#include <math.h>`

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking the `argc` to assure the command line argument actually exists.  other wise, the code with be accessing address 0 or some random location in memory.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns type `size_t` so the variable being assigned the returned value should also be `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: the variable `i` is being compared to the variable `len1` and `len2`  Therefore, since `len1` and `len2` should be `size_t` so should the variable `i`

Comment: regarding `argv[]`:  argv[0] is a pointer to a char string of the program name.  argv[1] is not being referenced within the posted code.   Suggest replacing all `argv[2]` with `argv[1]`  then replacing all `argv[3]` with `argv[2]`

Comment: if your allowed to use the C standard library, then: `result1 = atoi( &(argv[1][1]) );`   and similar for `result2`

Comment: when the `argv[]` is (per the value in `argc`) not containing the right number of parameters, then should output a 'usage' message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <firstNumber> <secondNumber\n", argv[0] );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
 char numcpy1[sizeof(argv[1])-1];
```

to

```
 char numcpy1[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
```

Ditto for `numcpy2`

Comment: Why `malloc()` instead of VLA?

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator does not give you the length of a string, as you seem to  think it does.  It tell you the *size of the datatype*.  Since `argv[2]` is a `char *`, this evaluates to the size of this pointer, most likely 4 or 8 depending on the system.

If the string in question is longer than this value, you end up writing past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case manifests as an unexpected result.

If you want the length of the string, use the `strlen` function instead.  Also, you need to add one more byte.  Strings in C are null terminated, so you need space for the null byte that marks the end of the string.

```
char numcpy1[strlen(argv[2])];
char numcpy2[strlen(argv[3])];
```

Also note that we don't need to add 1 to each of these since the first character in each string isn't copied.

Comment: @DaveRager Remove else-block instead `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of copying the numbers you could work more easily with pointers. Thereby, you don't have to think about memory allocation and copying the values just for the sake of converting them into an integer value:

```
const char *numcpy1 = argv[2][0]=='\0' ? argv[2] : argv[2]+1;
...
```